# what is best practice for decimal validate in laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have migration like this:

```
$table->decimal('amount_settle', 15, 2);
```

how can validate `amount_settle` in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

through laravel validator you can validate this one by following line of code

```
$request->validate(["amount_settle"=>'required|numeric|between:0,99.99']);
```